# composer1.0.0-alpha9が使えません。

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer

環境はubuntuで、php7.0インストール済みです。個人的な事情で、composer1.0.0-alpha9のバージョンじゃないとダメです。
公式サイトからcomposer1.0.0-alpha9をインストールしました。そのあとに、composerを使おうと思ったら、以下のようなエラーが出てきます。

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/String.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/String.php on line 18

PHP7がだめだと思い

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0
```

と入力して削除しました。次に、php5.4をインストールしようと

```
sudo apt-get install php5.4
```

と入力したら以下のように表示されました。

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package php5.4
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.4'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.4'
>   と表示されました。どうすれば解決できますか？

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/140269

Comment: すいません、それでもわからないのでここで質問しています。

Comment: 回答しようとする方への情報提供ですので、お気になさらず。

Comment: そうだったんですね、すいません,,,,,,,,